# Is there a way to make the launcher get out of the way of open windows?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, launcher

Is there a way to make the launcher "dodge" open windows in Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in Unity on 10.10.

This feature is enabled (and turned on by default) in 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

when using web browser i will use F11 to max and hide side bar. i have net book 10.10 running and  you'll get used to it :)